# Joomla 3.x and K2, no items categories or tags showing

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla 3 installation with K2 installed. After having to perform a database restore, none of my K2 content is visible from administrator despite being present in the database. I have tried a database repair, a fresh install of Joomla and K2, and i have tested the k2 language filters which is a previously known bug. Any suggestions on how to get my content back?

Comment: are you sure you've restored all the necessary database tables? I've had to do the same myself and it worked fine for me

Comment: yes i did an full export from my development site and imported the sql file from phpmyadmin